# CUDA 10.1 compile error with SFINAE templates

Tags: c++11, cuda

CUDA 10.1
g++ 7.3

For the purposes of a unit testing suite, I need large sets of repeatable data (more than can be hard-coded). I came up with this "generator" paradigm, with the idea that it could be used to fill arbitrary containers with data.

Now I need to extend the generator to populate multivalue containers (`float2`, `int2`, `thrust::complex`). My solution is to use SFINAE to conditionally define a function based on whether it can be constructed from a single value or requires a pair of values.

The below code compiles fine with GCC (`-std=c++1z`) but fails with nvcc (`-std=c++14`)

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class RandomGenerator
{
public:
    RandomGenerator(T min, T max, unsigned seed = 42);

    // Generate the next element in the sequence. This requires keeping all the necessary state
    // to advance
    T operator()();

    // fill a container if it is scalar
    template<typename Container>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<typename Container::value_type, T>>
    fill( Container& c );

    // fill a container if it takes 2 values (e.g., complex)
    template<typename Container>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<typename Container::value_type, T, T>>
    fill2( Container& c );

protected:
private:
    std::uniform_real_distribution< T > dist;
    std::mt19937 rng;
};


// Constructor - define the domain of this generation
template <typename T>
RandomGenerator<T>::RandomGenerator(T min, T max, unsigned seed)
    : dist(min, max)
    , rng()
{
    rng.seed(seed);
}

// generate one random number
template <typename T>
T
RandomGenerator<T>::operator()()
{
    return dist(rng);
}

template <typename T>
template<typename Container>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<typename Container::value_type, T>>
RandomGenerator<T>::fill( Container& c )
{
    std::generate(c.begin(), c.end(), *this);
}

template <typename T>
template<typename Container>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<typename Container::value_type, T, T>>
RandomGenerator<T>::fill2( Container& c )
{
    std::generate(c.begin(), c.end(), [this]() { return typename Container::value_type( (*this)(), (*this)() ); });
}
```

The compiler error:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc  -g -Xcompiler=-fPIE -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 --std=c++14 --use_fast_math -Xcompiler -pthread -x cu -dc unittest.cu -o unittest.cu.o
RandomGenerator.hh(30): error: namespace "std" has no member "is_constructible_v"

RandomGenerator.hh(30): error: type name is not allowed

RandomGenerator.hh(30): error: expected an identifier

RandomGenerator.hh(34): error: namespace "std" has no member "is_constructible_v"

RandomGenerator.hh(34): error: type name is not allowed

RandomGenerator.hh(34): error: too many arguments for alias template "std::enable_if_t"

RandomGenerator.hh(34): error: expected an identifier

RandomGenerator.hh(63): error: namespace "std" has no member "is_constructible_v"

RandomGenerator.hh(63): error: type name is not allowed

RandomGenerator.hh(63): error: expected an identifier

RandomGenerator.hh(71): error: namespace "std" has no member "is_constructible_v"

RandomGenerator.hh(71): error: type name is not allowed

RandomGenerator.hh(71): error: too many arguments for alias template "std::enable_if_t"

RandomGenerator.hh(71): error: expected a ";"
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to pass this to CUDA?

---

UPDATE

It appears that the specific problem is with `std::enable_if_t`, `std::is_XXX_v`. If instead of these typdefs I use the more verbose form

```cpp
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<typename Container::value_type, T>::value>::type
```

then nvcc can handle it.

Comment: The C++ front end is known to be fragile against very complex template declarations. The obvious solution is to remove the `-x cu` flag

Comment: `std::is_constructible_v` is C++17 not C++14. `std::enable_if_t` is C++14 though. More generally: All `::value` shortcuts are C++17 and all `::type` shortcuts are C++14. So just use the long form for `is_constructible` and you are good.

Comment: if you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler error gives you the hint that it does not know anything about `std::is_constructible_v`.
This is not due to the switch from gcc to nvcc but from c++17 to c++14.
You have already found out that you can use the `::value` form instead and that's the way to go here. (Of course you *could* also expand the standard namespace if you plan to make c++17 a requirement for your project as soon as nvcc supports it.)

You can keep the `std::enable_if_t` though as that was already introduced in c++14.

---

More generally one can find that all `std::something_t` shortcuts are available from c++14 on but the `std::something_v` shortcuts were introduced in c++17.